# How can I get another crew member?

Tags: astroflux

I specialized by two basic crew members in Survival and Combat, and I have the spot to have another crew member who will develop Diplomacy. I'm already in Kapello and there is no sign of a station where I can buy crew members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "cantinas" across the galaxies where one can buy new crew members in exchange for Flux coins. The basic price is 150 Flux for a new crew member.

In the first system there is no cantina.